# DynamoDB: Querying of non-key values with comparisons

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Let's say we have many data tables structured as timestamp(hash) - value pairs, where values could be for example temperatures or other kinds of varied measurement data.

To get timestamps of certain values we can build a secondary index with value(hash) - timestamp(range), but what if we want to query the value with comparison operations like GT, LT, BETWEEN to get timestamps of a range of values?

Obviously, I want to avoid using scan. The only thing I've come up with is using a dummy hash key and putting the values+timestamps into range attribute, but I'm guessing this has its own problems (better or worse compared to scan?).

Is there a better solution or can this be done with DynamoDB at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the HASH then you can perform a query on the RANGE. To get around this you would need to denormalize your table, i.e. create a duplicate with the keys reversed. Although that seems like a bit of a pain in the butt, it is one of the tradeoffs that is at times required for all the performance benefits of a key value store.

Example for this case:
With both keys completely random, then you are out of luck. Rather than set your HASH as a dummy value you could try using a monthly time stamp instead, that way you should always be able to work out pragmatically what the hash should be. You can also then look at setting the range as a combination of both values separated by a hyphen, i.e. timestamp-value, then in the denormalized table, value-timestamp, that way you should be able to use the comparison operators with no performance hit.

Comment: Denormalization was what I was referring to by "building a secondary index". This, however, does not allow me to query the values, only get. Like stated above, I've thought of using a common hash key (a 'dummy') for all with values+timestamps in range key for querying, but I'm unsure of its performance or other problems it might have (partitioning) so I'm looking for alternatives here. Denormalization is not an issue (at least for now).

Comment: If they are both completely random, then I think you are out of luck. Suggestion: rather than set your HASH as a dummy value, use a monthly time stamp instead, that way you should always be able to work out pragmatically what the hash should be. You can also then look at setting the range as both values separated by a hyphen, i.e. timestamp-value, then in the denormalized table, value-timestamp, that way you should be able to use the GT, LT, BETWEEN operators with no performance hit.

Comment: Although not too fond of having to segment the data, I guess that's the trade-off I have to make to implement this.